# How to transform data in Self-Relation Location table data in POWER BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

| Id | Location Name | ParentId | Location Type Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | India | 0 | Country |
| 2 | Malavi | 0 | Country |
| 3 | Gujarat | 1 | State |
| 4 | Junagadh | 3 | District |
| 5 | Mendarada | 4 | Taluka |
| 6 | MalaviGovernarate | 2 | Governarate |
| 7 | MalaviRegion | 6 | Region |
| 8 | MalaviSubRegion | 7 | Sub Region |
| 9 | MalaviVillage | 8 | Village |
| 10 | Jamka | 5 | Village |

**I have the above table and I want to transform it like below dynamically.**

| Id | Location Name | Country | State | District | Taluka | Governarate | Region | Sub Region | Village |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | India | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | Gujarat | India | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | Junagadh | India | Gujarat | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 4 | Mendarada | India | Gujarat | Junagadh NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |  |
| 5 | Jamka | India | Gujarat | Junagadh | Mendarada | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 6 | MalaviGovernarate | Malavi | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 7 | MalaviRegion | Malavi | NULL | NULL | NULL | MalaviGovernarate | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 8 | MalaviSubRegion | Malavi | NULL | NULL | NULL | MalaviGovernarate | MalaviRegion | NULL | NULL |
| 9 | MalaviVillage | Malavi | NULL | NULL | NULL | MalaviGovernarate | MalaviRegion | MalaviSubRegion | NULL |

**Can we achieve this in Microsoft Power BI?**

Answer (score 0):

There are dedicated DAX functions for flattening parent/child hierarcies, See  [Understanding functions for parent-child hierarchies in DAX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/understanding-functions-for-parent-child-hierarchies-in-dax)

See also

> Parent-child hierarchies are often used to represent charts of accounts, stores, salespersons and such. Parent-child hierarchies have a peculiar way of storing the hierarchy in the sense that they have a variable depth. In this pattern we show how to use parent-child hierarchies to show budget, actual and forecast values in a report using both a chart of accounts and a geographic hierarchy.

https://www.daxpatterns.com/parent-child-hierarchies/